# Can you index the isDeleted field? If so, how do you calculate the selectivity threshold

Tags: largedatavolumes, indexing, custom-index

Can you index the standard isDeleted field? If so, in terms of [calculating the selectivity threshold](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/194/0/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf), would it be considered a unary standard or unary custom index?

I'm working with large data volumes and other constraints, so this could be helpful if I could use this is a possible solution.